# How do I change this polarity in VSource?

Tags: circuitikz

I wanted to reverse the polarity of the sinusoidal source. How do I do it?

[image]

Comment: Can you please add the code, a complete, compilable one? It's probably a matter of saying `sV, v<=...`, but without knowing the details (`circuitikz` options, etc.) we can't really help you.

Answer (score 1):

you can choose the sens by using `sV<=$V$` or `sV>=$V$`

```
\begin{circuitikz}[american]
\draw (0,1) to[sV<=$V$] ++(3,0);
\end{circuitikz}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code fragment to an MWE (Minimal Working Example). BTW. OP's voltage source is vertical directed ...